# How to automate the process of unzip steps in RStudio

Tags: directory, rstudio, unzip

I have downloaded the transportation history data. The data for each year contain the same numbers of files with exactly same name. Each year's data was zipped in a single files.  I am trying to automate the process of unzipping.
for example: I have three zip files named (2014.zip, 2013.zip, 2012.zip) and each zip file contains three files(car.csv, truck.csv, train.csv). What I want is to unzip these files in their corresponding folders which will be created on the fly. How can I automate this process in RStudio? Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, how do you currently unzip them, in terms of programs or commands you are using?

Comment: I can automate the download process but not the unzip process. I have to do it manually if I can not automate this process.

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: I am using windows 7, RStudio Version 0.99.491

Comment: I solved it , here is the code

Comment: lapply(filenames, function(x){
    foldername<-substr(filename, 1, nchar(filename)-4)

    if (file.exists(x)==FALSE){
        download.file(url, x)
    }

    if (file.exists(foldername)==FALSE){
        dir.create(foldername)
    }

    unzip(x)

    for (file in list.files(pattern="*.dbf")){
        file.copy(file,foldername)

        file.remove(file)
    }
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lapply(filenames, function(x)){
foldername<-substr(filename, 1, nchar(filename)-4)

if (file.exists(x)==FALSE){
    download.file(url, x)
}

if (file.exists(foldername)==FALSE){
    dir.create(foldername)
}

unzip(x)

for (file in list.files(pattern="*.dbf")){
    file.copy(file,foldername)

    file.remove(file)
}}
```